# Preparing data for Multinomial Naive Bayes and running algorithm - ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, naivebayes, tfidfvectorizer

I want to run Multinomial NB algorithm to predict how many thumbs up will comment get on Google Play.
Data are scraped from offline navigation applications reviews.

I tried to run the algorithms using lists but it doesn't help, input must be string.
While I'm looking at the length of datasets, they look equal:

[image]

After I c/p from excel to notepad and c/p back both documents look like they have the equal number of rows.

But Python doesn't think so, this is the error I get:

```
<ipython-input-15-e013b17d1a55> in <module>
     18 
     19 #Split as training and testing sets
---> 20 xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(tfidf, int_classes, test_size=0.2, random_state=0, stratify=thumbs)
     21 
     22 #Build the model

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_split.py in train_test_split(*arrays, **options)
   2125         raise TypeError("Invalid parameters passed: %s" % str(options))
   2126 
-> 2127     arrays = indexable(*arrays)
   2128 
   2129     n_samples = _num_samples(arrays[0])

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in indexable(*iterables)
    291     """
    292     result = [_make_indexable(X) for X in iterables]
--> 293     check_consistent_length(*result)
    294     return result
    295 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    255     if len(uniques) > 1:
    256         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
--> 257                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
    258 
    259 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [139736, 134145]
```

This is the code:

```
import os
import nltk
import nltk.corpus 
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel("All_Apps_unicode.xlsx", parse_dates=['date'])

df.head()

df.info()

#Read reviews
with open ("app_reviews.txt", "r", encoding="utf8") as reviews:  
    descriptions = reviews.read().splitlines()
print("Sample review description :", descriptions[:2])

#Setup stopwords
import nltk
#nltk.download('stopwords')
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

#setup wordnet for lemmatization
#nltk.download('wordnet')
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

#Custom tokenizer that will perform tokenization, stopword removal and lemmatization
def customtokenize(str):
    tokens=nltk.word_tokenize(str)
    nostop = list(filter(lambda token: token not in stopwords.words('english'), tokens))
    lemmatized=[lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in nostop ]
    return lemmatized

#Generate TFIDF matrix
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=customtokenize)
tfidf=vectorizer.fit_transform(descriptions)

print("\nSample feature names identified : ", vectorizer.get_feature_names()[:25])
print("\nSize of TFIDF matrix : ",tfidf.shape)

#Loading the pre-built classifications for training
with open("app_thumbs.txt", 'r', encoding="utf8") as thumbs:  
    classifications = thumbs.read().splitlines()

#Create Labels and integer classes
from sklearn import preprocessing

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(classifications)
print("Classes found : ", le.classes_)

#Convert classes to integers for use with ML
int_classes = le.transform(classifications)
print("\nClasses converted to integers :", int_classes)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

#Split as training and testing sets
xtrain, xtest, ytrain, ytest = train_test_split(tfidf, int_classes, test_size=0.2, random_state=0, stratify=thumbs)

#Build the model
classifier= MultinomialNB().fit(xtrain, train)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your df has equal number of values across columns. Yet pandas assigns a NaN value to values missing from the data. I believe you have not treated your missing values yet. Hence the difference.

Please read more about missing values and their treatment here:

https://towardsdatascience.com/handling-missing-values-with-pandas-b876bf6f008f

Comment: Thank you for an answer and link but that isn't the case. I checked for missing in Pandas and they are zero for both `df['review]` and `df['thumb]`. For some reason, Python adds rows to reviews so their number grows from 134145(+1 for header) to 139736.